# c# start task2 aftert task1 is completed

Tags: c#, asynchronous, cmd, task

So If the task1 cmd cookie delete is completed after run task2. I want to make 2or3 cookie delete but not in the sam,but still runing in the same time.

```
            Task task1 = new Task(() =>
            {
                string cDelete;
                cDelete = "/c Javaws -uninstall & RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2 & echo off | clip ";
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", cDelete);

            });
            Task task2 = new Task(() =>
            {
                string cDelete;
                cDelete = "/c Javaws -uninstall & RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2 & echo off | clip ";
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", cDelete);

            });
            task1.Start();
            if (task1.IsCompleted)
            {
                task2.Start();
            }
```

Comment: Doing it with Tasks will only wait until the process is executed/started. Instead you should use the process and call `WaitUntilExit` on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Process directly.

```
public static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        using (Process myProcess = new Process())
        {
            myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments  = "/c Javaws -uninstall & RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2 & echo off | clip ";
            myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            myProcess.Start();
            // This code assumes the process you are starting will terminate itself. 
            // Given that is is started without a window so you cannot terminate it 
            // on the desktop, it must terminate itself or you can do it programmatically
            // from this application using the Kill method.
            myProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to call task.wait() to make sure the task is completed before you start task2

```
            Task task1 = new Task(() =>
            {
                string cDelete;
                cDelete = "/c Javaws -uninstall & RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2 & echo off | clip ";
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", cDelete);

            });
            Task task2 = new Task(() =>
            {
                string cDelete;
                cDelete = "/c Javaws -uninstall & RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2 & echo off | clip ";
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", cDelete);

            });
            task1.Start();
            task.Wait(); //add this line
            if (task1.IsCompleted)
            {
                task2.Start();
            }
```